# In BPMN JS how to get process ID and process name

Tags: bpmn, bpmn.io

In addition to parsing XML, can I get the ID and name of the process through the API of BPMN?

At present, it is realized in the following ways.

Parse XML to get process name;Convert XML to JSON to get process name

Answer (score 0):

You can get these information using [bpmn-js-properties-panel](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-properties-panel/) extension